# Unknown CMake command "add_jar" when trying to compile Java

Tags: java, cmake

As I understand, cmake supports java since version 2.8.6. I have found the command add_jar but I can't seem to get it to work. My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)
find_package(Java)

FILE(GLOB source
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.java"
)

add_jar(hello ${source})
```

And when I run cmake I get this:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.7.3
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Found Java: /usr/bin/java (found version "1.7.0.25") 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (add_jar):
  Unknown CMake command "add_jar".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to include the [`UseJava`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#module%3aUseJava) module as well.

```
find_package(Java)
include(UseJava)

add_jar(hello ${source})
```

The `find_package` call only determines the location of your Java installation on disk, while the `UseJava` module provides the functions for using Java (like `add_jar`). As stated by the documentation, the former is a prerequisite for loading the latter.